# Delete a document with a forward-slash in id from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document as:

```
{
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "U_6900/17",
    "_source": {
        "name": "User name"
    }
}
```

I tried to delete this record using:

```
DELETE user_entity/users/_query
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
             "id": "U_6900/17"
        }
    }
}
```

This does not delete the entry as the forward slash in "id" field separates the query.

How can I delete this record from Elasticsearch? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in two ways. Either by referencing the document directly like 
this:

```
DELETE user_entity/users/U_6900%2F17
```

Or via an [`ids` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) like this:

```
DELETE user_entity/users/_query
{
    "query": {
        "ids": {
             "values": ["U_6900/17"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work :/ First one gives a No handler found for uri error and the second one doesn't delete the reocrd.

Comment: Please, check again, I forgot to URL encode the slash

Comment: How about 2 forward slashes? seems like even with two encoded forward slashes, it'll decode to 1 forward slash